Bayesian vs frequentist difference beyond interpretation from the algebraic or categorical standpoint
Context: I'm not a statistician at all, and I was just involved in a debate between physicists on fundamental differences between the bayesian and frequentist approaches. Someone was arguing that it's just a difference of interpretation that has no mathematical implication. But I have the feeling (without explanation) that the algebraic structures/categories involved in both approach are different and that saying that there is a rigorous general equivalence between both approach is a bold statement. But as I am not a statistician, I have hard time going beyond this feeling.
Question: Is the difference between bayesian and frequentist approach purely interpretational, or are there cases (even if they are edge cases) where both approach would differ? Is there a general equivalence established between both approaches?
Any paper discussing that from an algebraic or categorical standpoint would be very valuable to me.

There is a philosophical difference in the sense that the two approaches are answering different questions.  Sometimes the results appear similar sometimes radically different, not helped by there being several different frequentist approaches (and perhaps different Bayesian starting points).

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22/bayesian-and-frequentist-reasoning-in-plain-english and the questions linked to it have some statisticians' replies
